# Retrieve and fetch a String from a text file inside server in android

Tags: android

***Our current Implementation***

We have an app which have following code for providing a series of string arrays. It will use the below String array to show images inside the app.

```
public class Images {

       public final static String[] ImageView_Urls = new String[] {
                "http://www.example.com/Image_1.jpg",
                "http://www.example.com/Image_2.jpg",
                "http://www.example.com/Image_3.jpg",
        };

    }
```

***Challenge or Our Requirement***

So if we need to add one more image, we need to do the changes inside the code and republish the application.So instead we added a text file with below information inside our server and we have a URL of that text file.Which is publicly available

**http://www.OurOwnServer.org/uploads/images.txt**

Above text file contain the updated data with 4 image urls.

```
            "http://www.example.com/Image_1.jpg",
            "http://www.example.com/Image_2.jpg",
            "http://www.example.com/Image_3.jpg",
            "http://www.example.com/Image_4.jpg", // added one more image here
```

So how can we retrieve the data from the server from above URL and store it inside the string **ImageView_Urls** Every time application starts.

NOTE: We know using API like volley etc to retrieve json/xml file and uploading the images directly inside server is the accurate method, but we have a special requirement where images are not in our servers and only thing we can do is update the text file manually.

Thanks

Comment: every time, App will download this file and replace new contents with old contents or file data. It will be easy to manage that way I guess !

Comment: Nope, we prefer to fetch the data directly without downloading.Because we dont want to give users a text file with bunch of data that can be opened inside their devices..

Comment: you can encrypt that file easily using any Encryption Algorithm !

Comment: second way is, run one cronjob from server, which will continuously update file to your server. And when in App that needed, App send one signal to server that App need that file things, at that time Server fetch data from that file and send to App using push notification or in Simple API as per your flow of App. But it is also good solution. So that this way you can achieve what you want ! just give it a Try !

Comment: If you don't want to let the app download the file because the user might open it, keep in mind that the user could decompile the code. My 2 cents: whatever data you give to a client (including the app code itself), just assume that will be opened with malicious intent

Comment: @lelloman I think we are just complicating the requirement.

Comment: my point is that there is no reason to have a fixed file inside the app resources, just ship one with the apk and then eventually download a new version. if you are worried about the user opening the file it can do it anyway

Comment: But what if we need to have few more text files like this, We just need string from the text, we dont need text file to be inside the apk..

Comment: yeah, i think you don't need text files inside the apk too, i now realize that i misread the question lol :) so just google "android download text file"!!!